# Jquery Ajax: How to pass bootstrap typhead input to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-typeahead

I am learning about retrieving data from database for `typehead` input.I was trying to follow this tutorial [Ajax to Bootstrap Typeahead From Database](http://blog.calebnance.com/jquery/how-to-add-ajax-to-bootstrap-typeahead-from-mysql-step-by-step.html)
In the beginning, i want to see whether the ajax is sending the data to `php file`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
        $('input.typeahead').typeahead({     
          source: function (typeahead,query) {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'data.php',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'JSON',
              data: 'query=' + query,
     async: false,
              success: function(data) {      
                console.log(data);
               
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/typeahead.min.js"></script>   
   </head>
   <body >
      <div class="container"  >
         <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary"  >
               <div class="panel-heading" >
                  <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">Test</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" >
                      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="acode">Item Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5 " id = "empid" >                        
         <div class="  input-group ">            
            <input type="text" class=" form-control typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" name="itemname"  id="item"  placeholder="Enter Item"> 
            </div>
        </div>
                        </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>      
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is my data.php:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST;    
?>
```

However Iam getting this error: `Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is required`.Do i need `bloodhound` `remote` or another library I don't Know.I am stuck as a novice.Please Please Please help Me.Thanks

Comment: And your question is what?

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Q for quick response.I want to see that whatever data i insert to `typehead`,then this data will go to `data.php` returns back to html page.Thanks

Comment: you are doing console.log(data) right? you can see your console to see what response you are getting right? alternatively you can see the network tab of the inspector on your browser to see what data is being sent with the request.